# Unable to repartition with gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ntfs, ext4

I now have a 1 TB [ext4 partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7n3C.png), but I can't change that with gparted.

How can I partition the hard disk into 600GB and 300GB?
Should it stay as ext4 or should I change it to NTFS?
I have only one OS installed.

Comment: You'll want to use ext4

Comment: According to your image you have one partition = sda1 931MB. Delete the partition, and create new: sda1 600MB, sda2 331MB.

Comment: disk is in use.now can i delete partition , if i use liveUSB will i have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Based on subsequent comment, you wish to preserve your Ubuntu 17.10 install and create a new 18.04 install in the other partition.  You can repartition that drive without losing the original installation.

It requires rebooting with a LiveUSB, and then running *gparted* to shrink the current partition, leaving space at its end to create a new partition. Save the changes, shut down, remove the Live USB, and power back up; you will then have two partitions. The first partition, **sda1**, will be bootable and contain your operating system and the apps installed with Linux as well as any added after installation.

In the future you may wish to consider keeping your data in a separate partition, by assigning /home to that partition. Then, since all your data goes into /home with normal use, you can be assured that any new install will not alter your data.

Comment: I want to make sure i don't loose my data because i was using 17.10 and i could not upgraded to 18.04 so i had backup my data and then install Ubuntu clean. there was no way i knew to upgrade like windows. create Ubuntu disk(pendrive) is live disk isn't there i choose use without install and then i download gparted and use to repartition.